# jQuery accordion plugin: how do I get accordion clicked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

this is an easy question, I know, but I can't figure it out from the jQuery docs. I'm using the accordion plugin and I want to have a function called when the user clicks an accordion fold... and I need to know which fold they clicked.

I see I can use changestart and that's the code I have so far... but I dumped the newContent object and I don't see a simple "id" value, or something that corresponds to which accordion fold was clicked. I just want a number, like 0-5 if there are 6 folds.

```
$("#galleryaccordion").accordion({
    changestart: function(event, ui) {
        // when user clicks accordion fold, figure out which one
        // console.log(ui.newContent);
    }
});
```

Thanks--

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use the "active" value from the "options" object.

change: function(event, ui) { 
                                    alert(ui.options.active.toString());
                                }

this throws up the ID of the active pane (the one that was just selected).

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) - you are looking for `ui.newHeader`.

```
$("#galleryaccordion").accordion({
    change: function(event, ui) {
        ui.newHeader // jQuery object, activated header
        ui.oldHeader // jQuery object, previous header
        ui.newContent // jQuery object, activated content
        ui.oldContent // jQuery object, previous content
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi Josiah-- I saw that in the docs but that doesn't help me. I need the ID number of which element was clicked in the accordion. I dumped those objects to firebug and didn't see what I was after. (Incidentally, this is my frustration with the jQuery docs-- they're like "here's an object, good luck!" :-) Wish things were enumerated a bit more.)

Comment: Ahh, I see. You were looking for the `index`.